# User profile fields translatable

Tags: 7, entities, users, i18n-l10n

How can I make user profile fields translatable?

I'd like to be able to translate some fields into other languages.

Comment: Translate field contents or field labels?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use extra modules, instead of simple t() coding (as I do not believe this is possible for what you desire), install [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [i18n Internationalization](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) modules. Then, follow this [guide in Profile translation](https://drupal.org/node/1118362) and its documentation and that should set you straight.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you create user profile with content profile you probably can use CCK translation module for this.

Comment: Unofortunately, as far as I know there's no content profile for D7.

Comment: Maybe other modules such as Localization Client? It probably goes by t() so maybe it can help. It is for D7 too, if want to translate labels etc.

Comment: Try Translation table module too

Comment: drupality, thanks for the tips, but L10N client helps with interface translation and Translation table - with taxonomy and menus so it doesn't apply to content itself.